# Using ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, xy, error-000229

Attempting to import and convert Excel spreadsheets to tables then add XY Coordinates to the tables. The tool runs and provide the output tables below, but I cannot get the second part of the tool to run properly and populate XY coordinates. I know that I can manually add the XY coordinates, but having the tool automatically create them is necessary for the purpose of this tool.

[image]

[image]

When I run the tool, an error message say it cannot find the tables in the the specified file path.

Is it possible in the same tool to add fields to an EXCEL to TABLE conversion?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The add XY coordinate tool requires a [feature layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-xy-coordinates.htm) you are providing a stand alone table.

Comment: Added the create feature layer tool, but it still fails when the tool reaches the select data. The message still says it cannot find the tables to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be way off here as I cannot offer the complete answer but wouldn't the tool be failing at the select data point because you have just imported the accounts from an excel spreadsheet, there has been no feature geometry created yet to assign XY coordinates to?